# Scala - parameter type in abstract base class that can be extended

Tags: scala, inheritance, types

How to provide a parameter for a method in abstract class so that the parameter can be extended later on? I will illustrate a simple scenario below.

```
abstract class Car {
  def drive(x: Driver)
}

abstract class Driver
case class DriverA(name: String) extends Driver
case class DriverB(name: String, age: Int) extends Driver

class Audi extends Car {
  // each child class should have a more specific type for param "x"
  def drive(x: DriverA) = { ... }
}

class BMW extends Car {
  // each child class should have a more specific type for param "x"
  def drive(x: DriverB) = { ... }
}
```

But this doesn't work in Scala: "Error: [..] method parameter types must match exactly"

I also tried specifying upper bound type like this def drive[T <: Driver](x: T): Int, but still without any luck. It seems that I am missing something simple and obvious.

Is there something wrong with design like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [abstract type](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/105) in scala:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

abstract class Car {
  type D <: Driver
  def drive(x: D): Unit
}
abstract class Driver
case class DriverA(name: String) extends Driver
case class DriverB(name: String) extends Driver
class Audi extends Car {
  type D = DriverA
  def drive(x: DriverA): Unit = println(x.name)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Car
defined class Driver
defined class DriverA
defined class DriverB
defined class Audi

scala> new Audi().drive(DriverA("test"))
test
```

Or use class parameterized with type:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

abstract class Driver
case class DriverA(name: String) extends Driver
abstract class Car[D <: Driver] {
  def drive(x: D): Unit
}
class Audi extends Car[DriverA] {
  def drive(x: DriverA) = println(x.name)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

scala> new Audi().drive(DriverA("zzz"))
zzz
```